# What were the sound changes in Old Novgorod?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change, slavic-languages

I'm into conlanging and got the idea of recreating a Novgorod language. I tried Wikipedia in both Russian and English, but I still don't understand the various sound changes as there isn't a lot of elaboration or examples. Could anyone help? Even if its just sources, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Wikipedia has everything explained, what exactly don't you understand and would like to be explained? The most detailed description of the Old Novgorod idiom is [_Древненовгородский диалект_](http://gramoty.ru/thumbs/bibliography_document_dnd-2.pdf) [Old Novgorodian dialects], 2004, by Andrey Zaliznyak (in Russian) which is in open access and includes a _215-page_ grammar of Old Novgorod as well as all of its corpus, the texts of the Novgorod birch-bark documents with commentaries. Have you read it? Have a look at it and get more specific questions rather than asking to retell 215 pages.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that